# function in javascript with two parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write function looks like `sum(2)(3)` which outputs 6. I am beginner here and tried some closure example but unable to do so. This is question asked in interview.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: **You can acheive this using closures in Javascript.**

Learn about [Javascript Closures][1] which are basically nested functions where we can chain functions to many levels until we reach a end, at which point it computes the value and returns the value of all above functions.
 
Variables declared outside of a nested function are also accessible inside the nested function.


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum function needs to return another function which also takes one parameter that you will pass with second parentheses.

```js
function sum(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b
  }
}

console.log(sum(2)(3))
```

Comment: Or using ES6 `let sum = a => b => a * b;`